# passing char pointer to the function in C. just first position is taken

Tags: c

I have a tiny problem. I want to pass a string (char pointer) to a function. In the function, I can just pass the first position of the char pointer.

Here is the code-snippet:

```
void put(struct DataItem* hashArray[SIZE], char* key){
struct DataItem* item = malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
item->key = *key;
item->value = 1;
```

So, when I call the debugger and check the value of "item->key". Then its just the first position of the char pointer.

For example I m passing "524234"
Then item->key is just "5"

EDIT:
Thanks for response

you mean I have to use strcpy like this

```
void put(struct DataItem* hashArray[SIZE], char* key){
struct DataItem* item = malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
strcpy(item->key,key);
item->value = 1;
```

it doesnt work.
even if I try it with a pointer like this

```
void put(struct DataItem* hashArray[SIZE], char* key){
struct DataItem* item = malloc(sizeof(struct DataItem));
strcpy(item->key,*key);
item->value = 1;
```

In the first situation the compiler says

> 16: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

In the second situation (with *). the compiler says:

> 16: warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]
>
> warning: passing argument 1 of 'strcpy' makes pointer from integer without a cast [-Wint-conversion]

EDIT:

Here is the struct DataItem

```
struct DataItem {
    char key;
    int value;
};
```

Comment: Please make a [mcve]. Definition of DataItem is relevant. It seems to only contain a `char` not a `char *`. The latter coudl be set to `key` instead of `*key` and thereby carry the pointer to the whole string. Or you need to string-copy...

Comment: What is the question? Why is this a "tiny problem"?

Comment: I think you may want to use a function like `strcpy` rather than dereferencing the char pointer with `*key`

Comment: show the struct definition

Comment: The code seems to do what it is supposed to do. If the code had been `item->key = *(key+1);` then `item->key` would become the single character `'2'` (not `"2"` which is a string).

Comment: What did you expect to happen? Your `DataItem` `key` is only a single character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your "struct DataItem" has storage for ONE single character. It doesn't have storage for a string.

So first, you need a char* here, not a char.

```
struct DataItem {
    char* key;
    int value;
};
```

Now we have the problem that *someone* must take responsibility for creating and deleting keys. I suggest first you create a typedef for DataItem, makes life easier:

```
typedef struct {
    char* key;
    int value;
} DataItem;
```

Then you write two functions like this:

```
DataItem* CreateDataItem (char* key, int value) {
    DataItem* item = malloc (sizeof (DataItem));
    char* copyKey = malloc (strlen (key) + 1);
    strcpy (copyKey, key);
    item->key = copyKey;
    item->value = value;
    return item;
}

void DestroyDataItem (DataItem* item) {
    free (item->key);
    free (item);
}
```

And now you create an item like this:

```
DataItem* item = CreateDataItem (key, 1);
```